# Remove/Reset Login screen message

Tags: macos, command-line, preferences

Recently, I wanted to put a message on my **Login** (not **Lock** Screen) screen and I did it with the following command:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow LoginwindowText "Message"
```

It took some time to appear for some reason but now I've been trying to remove that message for a while using the same command but leaving the `"Message"` part like `""`, as you can see in the following example:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow LoginwindowText ""
```

Yet, it does not disappear. Still there. How can I force my Mac to remove it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can reset a preference using `defaults delete`:

```
sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow LoginwindowText
```

Comment: It hasn't taken effect yet, I'm going to wait a little bit, just like when I applied the message.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not gone yet. Maybe it's the caches?

Comment: I can confirm this works! But! When you do it, go to  > System Preferences > Users & Groups > Change Password...
Then, all you need to do is... just type in your password, no need to actually change it, just type it in. My guess is that this resets the caches or those message settings completely from the system. I can't say for sure what it does but it's an option if this command does not do the job completely.